# setScene() method, JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scene

I have a program with few fxml files so at different points of program different scene and layout is shown.

```
some point in a program:
mainStage.setScene(FXMLScene1);
...
later in a program:
mainStage.setScene(FXMLScene2);
...
later in a program:
mainStage.setScene(FXMLScene2);
```

I wonder what happens to old scene when I use `setScene()` several times?

There are very complicated methods to change scene(like this https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1) and my solution is just to make static refference to main stage at MainApplication class so I can manage it everywhere.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public static Stage parentWindow;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        parentWindow = stage;
```

so it made me wonder if everything is allright with my concept...

Comment: Why do you want to change the scene everytime instead of just changing the Root of the scene?

Comment: Can you throw some light on your requirement?

Comment: Well my requirement is that my way of programming is effective, not computer memory consuming etc. Ive found this solution, I dont know about changing only the root...?

Comment: ahh, You mean `mainStage.getScene().setRoot(window1);` . I need to check how this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a new scene on your stage and keep no reference to the old scene or objects in it, the old scene will be garbage collected and all resources associated with it will be thrown away (whenever the garbage collector in the Java Virtual Machine decides to do so).  If you keep a reference to the old scene (e.g. assign it to a static final variable in your application), then the old scene resources will remain in memory until your application terminates.

> If I change the root, how to make Stage change to the new size(size of Layout)?

Use [`stage.sizeToScene()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--), which will: "Set the width and height of this Window to match the size of the content of this Window's Scene."  The stage sizing process when you invoke this call is similar to when you initially show a stage, but updated for the current scene's content and layout constraints.

The algorithm used is documented in the [Scene javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html): "The scene's size may be initialized by the application during construction. If no size is specified, the scene will automatically compute its initial size based on the preferred size of its content. If only one dimension is specified, the other dimension is computed using the specified dimension, respecting content bias of a root."

> what is better, to change the whole scene, or just a root?

I don't think it makes much difference, choose whichever strategy makes the most sense to you.

Comment: what is better, to change the whole scene, or just a root? Can you also reference to what I was asking in comment before, that is: if I change the root, how to make Stage change to the new size(size of Layout)?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create a scene to flip screens. You can directly set the root node on the present scene, using [setRoot()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setRoot-javafx.scene.Parent-) of the [Scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html).

This will save you the pain of creating a scene instance every time to want to change the content of your application.

You can use it:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getclass.getResource("some-fxml.fxml"));
scene.setRoot(root);
```

Just keep in mind the Parent element being used in the FXML that you want to set as the Root Element. From the docs

> The application must specify the root Node for the scene graph by setting the root property. If a Group is used as the root, the contents of the scene graph will be clipped by the scene's width and height and changes to the scene's size (if user resizes the stage) will not alter the layout of the scene graph. If a resizable node (layout Region or Control is set as the root, then the root's size will track the scene's size, causing the contents to be relayed out as necessary.

**N.B.** Please read through the [EXAMPLE](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1) that you have provided, it uses set**Screen**( ) instead of set**Scene**( ). The whole example has just one `Scene` and many `Screens`, where screens can be considered as any `child of the scene graph`

**Additional data as per comments**

If you go through the scene javadoc, you will find that `Scene resizes itself to the root size, if no predefined size is present`

> The scene's size may be initialized by the application during construction. If no size is specified, the scene will automatically compute its initial size based on the preferred size of its content. If only one dimension is specified, the other dimension is computed using the specified dimension, respecting content bias of a root.

**Different FXML have different size**

In case you have different FXML that you want to set as ROOT nodes and each of them have different sizes.Futhermore, you want to re-size your stage in accordance to every FXML that you load, then you will have to re-initialize the Scene, there is no other way.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getclass.getResource("some-fxml.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. But how can I make Stage resize to fit root Layout?

Comment: Do you want the root to resize the scene ?

Comment: Yes, I think thats what I want to happen.

Comment: Sorry, I start to get confused what is Scene, Root or Stage. Simply, when I load new FXML file, the Window size doest change so I have to manually resize the window to see rest of the controlls... why?

Comment: Ahh, the problem you are facing is because once a Root is loaded to a Scene, it set its own Height and Width according to the Root's size. Next time when we try to set the Root, the scene already has a Size and it won't re-size according to the Root. Under such conditions, when you want to get the stage to be re-sized, you can re-intialize your Scene.

Comment: how to re-initialize Scene? or You are saying I should use setScene() method...?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the [`stage.sizeToScene()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--) function Tomek.